# Size of maximum matching in bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I was wondering if there exists a way to compute the size of the maximum matching in a bipartite graph without having to compute the maximum matching itself.
Any help or direction will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could find the minimum vertex cover. According to the [König-Egerváry Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29), the minimum vertex cover is the same size as a maximum matching of any bipartite graph.

Comment: The algos i looked for finding the minimum vertex cover are all based on first finding the maximum matching.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar then with any algorithm of the sort you are looking for, however the randomized algorithm explained in [this paper](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mucha/pub/mucha_sankowski_focs04.pdf) runs pretty fast.